# variable is being used without being initialized when passing the array

Tags: c++

```
void initPLBP(double *mat)
{
    if (...)
    {
        int pcaDim = 10;
        int featureDim = 80;
    }
    mat = new double[10 * 80];
}


void main()
{
    double* pcaMat;
    initPLBP(pcaMat);
}
```

when i run the code, it says that "The variable 'pcaMat' is being used without being initialized". the question is i can't allocate memory for pcaMat in the main function(asked by some other reasons). is there any solution? thank you

Comment: First of all, use `int main`, not `void main`. Second, everything not a reference is pass-by-value.

Comment: I think you need to understand that assigning `mat` will not affect `pcaMat`. Please look at what is pass by value.

Answer (score 2):

What the compiler means is the variable 'pcaMat' (pointer) not be initialized, so it doesn't point to anything before used. Not the pointee.

```
void initPLBP(double *&mat)
{
    if (...)
    {
        int pcaDim = 10;
        int featureDim = 80;
    }
    mat = new double[10 * 80];
}

int main()
{
    double* pcaMat = 0;
    initPLBP(pcaMat);
}
```